# Understanding python script to create Kuhn Poker game tree

Tags: python, class, nodes, decision-tree, poker

For a University project I am trying to follow a script I have access to which supposedly creates the game tree structure for two player Kuhn Poker - written using Python's class structure.

When run it comes across problems with the children and parents properties of its decision nodes, and I can't grasp how the code is progressing step by step.

Can anybody clear this up for me? I have spent days poring over the code and feel knowledgeable opinions will be able to spot the problem.

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
import random
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import permutations
from itertools import combinations

J=11
Q=12
K=13
A=14

class specifications(object):
    def __init__(self, deck, size_of_bet, maximum_allowed_bet, ante):
            self.deck = deck
            self.ante = ante
            self.size_of_bet = size_of_bet
            self.maximum_allowed_bet = maximum_allowed_bet

class tree(object):
    def __init__(self, specifications):
            self.specifications = deepcopy(specifications)
            self.info = []
            self.root = None

    def start_game_and_deal_card(self):
        in_the_pot = [True] * 2
        players_contribution = [self.specifications.ante] * 2
        acting_player = 0
        bets = [0] * 2
        minimum_moves = in_the_pot.count(True)
        moves = 0
        game_so_far = ""
        possible_cards = permutations(combinations(self.specifications.deck,1),2)
        for cards in possible_cards:
            dealt_cards = ()
            cards = list(cards)
            for i,card in enumerate(cards):
                if in_the_pot[i]:
                    cards[i] = card + cards[i]
            for card in cards:
                dealt_cards += card
            deal = deal_cards_node(node, players_contribution, player_cards, self.specifications.deck, "")
            self.tree_structure(deal, acting_player, in_the_pot, players_contribution, cards, self.specifications.deck, game_so_far, minimum_moves, moves, bets)
        return deal

    def tree_structure(self, node, acting_player, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, minimum_moves, moves, bets):
        if in_the_pot.count(True) ==1:
            self.showdown(node, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, self.specifications.deck, game_so_far)
            return
        if moves>=minimum_moves and bets[node.player]==betlevel:
            self.showdown(node, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, self.specifications.deck, game_so_far)
            return
        decision = decision_node(node, players_contribution, player_cards, self.specifications.deck, game_so_far, acting_player)
        # update information set
        self.info.append(decision.player)
        acting_player = (acting_player + 1) % 2
        # fold child
        if players_contribution[decision.player] < max(players_contribution):
            game_so_far += 'f'
            in_the_pot[decision.player] = False
            self.tree_structure(node, acting_player, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, minimum_moves, moves + 1,bets)
            in_the_pot[decision.player] = True
            node.fold_decision = node.children[-1]
        # raise child
        if self.specifications.maximum_allowed_bet > max(bets):
            game_so_far += 'r'
            players_contribution[decision.player]=players_contribution[decision.player]+1
            bets[decision.player]=bets[decision.player]+1
            self.tree_structure(node, acting_player, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, minimum_moves, moves + 1, bets)
            node.raise_decision = node.children[-1]
        # call child
        game_so_far =+ 'c'
        players_contribution[node.player]=players_contribution[(node.player+1)%2]
        bets[node.player]=bets[(node.player+1)%2]
        self.tree_structure(node, acting_player, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, minimum_moves, moves + 1, bets)
        node.call_decision = node.children[-1]
        return decision

    def showdown(self, node, in_the_pot, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far):
        if in_the_pot.count(True) == 1:
            winners = in_the_pot
        else:
            winners = []
            if player_cards[0] > player_cards[1]:
                winners.append(0)
            if player_cards[0] < player_cards[1]:
                winners.append(1)
        total = sum(players_contribution)
        payoffs = winners.extend([total])
        return terminal_node(node, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, payoffs, in_the_pot)

class node(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far):
        self.deck = deepcopy(deck)
        self.players_contribution = deepcopy(players_contribution)
        self.player_cards = deepcopy(player_cards)
        self.parent = parent

class terminal_node(node):
    def __init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, payoffs, in_the_pot):
        node.__init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far)
        self.children = []

class deal_cards_node(node):
    def __init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far):
        node.__init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far)
        self.children = []

class decision_node(node):
    def __init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far, player):
        node.__init__(self, parent, players_contribution, player_cards, deck, game_so_far)
        self.player = player
        self.children = []
        self.raise_decision = None
        self.call_decision = None
        self.fold_decision = None
```

Comment: This code is a mess, and is incomplete. It also isn't traditional Kuhn Poker if there's a Ace involved.

Comment: You are correct - I am led to believe this is the half-street AKQ version of the simplified Kuhn version. I am struggling to make sense of how the children lists at the node classes are updated, and how the player_cards referred to throughout is formed.

Comment: I believe this code has been based off the pycfr github library, "pokertrees" script.